# failed to load config from C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\my_app\vite.config.js error during build: Error: Cannot find module 'node:path'

Tags: php, node.js, laravel

[image]

When i install npm run build in laravel Vite manifest not found at: C:\xampp\htdocs\lec\FDC_lecture\laravel\my_app\public\build/manifest.json

Comment: I think you are using an old version of Node. If you need to keep that version, change your code to load the module as just `path` instead of `node:path`.

Comment: @CherryDT your answer is very powerful.. the problem is gone .. Thanks sir

Answer (score 0):

I think one way is to try with newer node.js versions (after 18), or if you are using node.js 20, try to downgrade to 18 LTS.

You can use `nvm` for that.

Also clearing the cache of laravel by running `php artisan cache:clear` can help a lot.

Also you can try changing your code to load the module as just `path` instead of `node:path`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks alot ,  your tip fixed my problem.. the nwer versin of node is more reliable for my project. thank

Comment: @YeKyaw Im glad. please upvote and accept the answer as I see a downvote! I dont know why! :)